# using Python, I do not know how to calculate the Second-order Lax scheme of the given function with non-constant velocity in this density function

Tags: python, physics, differential-equations, computation

[enter image description here][1]

strong text [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9yDK.png

I have tried to code this with constant velocity but I am confused how to do it with the velocity given as v=10+x:
here is my code for constant velocity:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# number of iterations
MaxIter   = 800                           
# no. of points
Nx        = 1000 
# propagation velocity
c         = 10.0                           
xmin      = 0.0
xmax      = 100
v         = 0.2                           

dx        = (xmax - xmin) / Nx
dt        = (v/c) * dx

oldL       = np.concatenate((np.zeros(100) , [1.0]*(100) , np.zeros(8*100)))  # initial rho density
newL       = np.zeros(Nx)                  
# initializing a 2nd array for updating the results
newL[0]    = 0.0                           
# forcing the boundary condition rho(0) = 0
newL[Nx-1] = 0.0                           
# forcing the boundary condition rho(10) = 0 

j =0
# main loop 
while j < MaxIter :    

    for i in range(1,Nx-1): # loop inside the array, note the bounds
        newL[i] = (oldL[i+1] + oldL[i-1])/2.0 - 0.5*v*(oldL[i+1]-oldL[i-1])

    oldL = newL[:]                            
  # duplicating array "new"
    j += 1

print( "No. of samples    =" , Nx)
print("No. of iterations =" , MaxIter) 
print ("delta x           =" , dx)
print ("delta t           =" , dt)

xs = [ dx * float(i) for i in range(Nx)] 
# "x" values for this dicretization: Dx * i

# Naming the x-axis, y-axis and the whole graph
plt.xlabel("x(m)")
plt.ylabel("rho(x)")
plt.title("Homework Assignment 3")

plt.scatter(xs, newL , color='b', label='Lax'   )
plt.legend()
# Adding legend, which helps us recognize the curve according to it's color
plt.show()  
# To load the display window
```

Comment: Why is the picture redacted ██████ of a █████ blacked out ██████?

Comment: I am not sure why the image is blacked out but there is no specific information there , only the word constant is blacked out

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the second equation for the finite volume scheme where in the two flux formulae you replace`v_i` with your velocity equation `10+oldL[i]`, so

```
FR = 0.5*(10+oldL[i+1])*(oldL[i+2] + oldL[i+1])
FL = 0.5*(10+oldL[i-1])*(oldL[i-1] + oldL[i-2])
newL[i] = (oldL[i+1] + oldL[i-1])/2.0 - 0.5*(dt/dx)*(FR-FL)
```

The normalization constant `(dt/dx)` you'll have to choose based on how you would like your steps to be.

As a check you can take constant `v` instead and replace it with `0.2` and expect to get the same result with the code you posted.

Comment: alright, thank you: there is one issue for replacing v_i with 10+oldL[i]: